# tikz: Multiple splits of rectangle

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to get this one with `tikz`.

[image]

This is what I got so far

[image: tikz]

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
%\documentclass[border=10pt]{article}


\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary {shapes.multipart}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\tikzset{every node/.style={rectangle split, draw, minimum width = 0.5cm}}

\node[rectangle split part fill={green!50}]  {};
\node[rectangle split part fill={yellow!50}]at (0.5, 0){};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Any hints, please.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/192523/using-tikz-to-draw-array-figures/192545#192545

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with some manual tweaks ...

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,
                shapes.multipart}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 0pt,
  VMPN/.style = {rectangle split,rectangle split parts=5,
                 draw,
                 fill=#1,
                 text width=4cm, align=center,
                 inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt}
                        ]
\node (n1)  [VMPN=green!30,
             label=Urban]  {\nodepart{one}  \vphantom{$B_1^2$}
                            \nodepart{two}  \vphantom{$B_1^2$}
                            \nodepart{three}  ~\\ $\vdots$\\[-1ex]~
                            \nodepart{four} \vphantom{$B_1^2$}
                            \nodepart[inner ysep=0pt]{five}
             \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{*{4}{>{$}C<{$}|}@{}}
                H_1 &   H_2 &   \dots   &   H_{10}
             \end{tabularx}
                            };
\node (n2)  [VMPN=yellow!30,
             right=of n1,
             label=Rural]  {\nodepart{one}  \vphantom{$B_1^2$}
                            \nodepart{two}  \vphantom{$B_1^2$}
                            \nodepart{three} ~\\   $\vdots$\\[-1ex]~
                            \nodepart{four} ~\vphantom{$B_1^2$}
                            \nodepart[inner ysep=0pt]{five}
              \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{*{4}{>{$}C<{$}|}@{}}
                H_1 &   H_2 &   \dots   &   H_{10}
             \end{tabularx}
                            };
\node[left=of n1.one   west]  {$B_1$};
\node[left=of n1.two   west]  {$B_2$};
\node[left=2mm of n1.three west]  {$\vdots^{}_{_~}$};
\node[left=of n1.four  west]  {$B_{19}$};
\node[left=of n1.five  west]  {$B_{20}$};

\node[right=of n2.one   east]  {$B_1$};
\node[right=of n2.two   east]  {$B_2$};
\node[right=2mm of n2.three east]  {$\vdots^{}_{_~}$};
\node[right=of n2.four  east]  {$B_{49}$};
\node[right=of n2.five  east]  {$B_{50}$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Edit:**
Colors of nodes' labels (Urban, Rural) you can change on two ways:

- with `label=\textcolor{red}{Urban}` as is done in above MWE, or
- with  `label={[text=red]Urban}`

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Zarko for very useful answer. Would appreciate if you guide how to change the color of text Urban and Rural. Thanks

Comment: @MYaseen208, see edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

On the lines of your requirement--the last row can be split using `tikz/multipart`--I have not punched in all the data

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{tikz,tikz-qtree}
%\usetikzlibrary{shapes,trees}
 \usetikzlibrary {shapes.multipart,positioning}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
 \tikzset{
            rect1/.style={
                        rectangle split,
                        rectangle split parts=4, 
                        draw, 
                        minimum width=4cm,
%                       minimum height=1cm
                        },
            rect2/.style={
                        rectangle,
%                       rectangle split parts=4, 
%                       draw, 
                        minimum width=1cm
                        }       
         }
 \node[rect1,fill={yellow!30}]          (r1) at (1.5,0) {};
 \node[rect1, fill={green!30}]               at (5.5,0) {};
 \node[rect2, ]                         (r2) at (1.5,1) {d};
 \node[rect2, ]                              at (5.5,1) {h};
 \node[rect2,left=of r1.one split west,shift={(1cm,5pt)}]   (r3) {1};
 \node[rect2,left=of r1.two split west,shift={(1cm,5pt)}]        {2};
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```